Connect a smart plug with other device using bluetooth
I am working on a project for the IoT course at university. I need to create a system that allows us to know which devices are connected via Bluetooth to a smart plug. I have seen that there are different types of smart plugs that have both a WiFi module and a Bluetooth module. My idea is that various devices can connect via Bluetooth to the plug, and the smart plug uses its WiFi module to communicate the names of the connected devices to a web server. Is there a commercially available smart plug that allows for this? If not, is there any other solution that uses APIs to solve this problem?

try to build your own

I doubt you will find something off the shelf that does that, especially as a BLE client ("central") is unlikely to spontaneously communicate its name (whatever that may mean) to the server ("peripheral"), at least at the BLE level. Whatever protocol used would need to include this info, and the smart plug would need to remember it and be able to report it. You would probably need to develop your own device and smartphone app. Also what does "connected" mean? Connected once? Currently connected (i.e. app active on the smartphone, smartphone in range)? Something else?

Commercial devices that uses ESP32 (Note not all ESP32 chip has the BLE feature) can potentially do what you describe.
Tasmota has a web page with some devices that have potential to support your requirements, check https://tasmota.github.io/docs/Bluetooth_ESP32/
Another solution is to build your own device, there are a lot of easily available ESP32 based development boards that could be used together with other relay/solid state relays to give you the features and requirements, as jsotola pointed out in a comment.

Bluetooth LE has a limited range in the order of 10m.  While a host / server may communicate with Wifi and Bluetooth at the same time, individual plugs will not.  That's not what they are designed for.
A plug being a "slave" is not designed to talk to neighbouring devices in that fashion. Many devices are locked to one "server" at a time, meaning that they may not connect to multiple networks at the same time.
Assuming that (for example) they are Zwave devices, then you can get a cheap Z-Stick which will plug into your desktop and communicate with all the devices.  You only have to figure out hot "hack" into one system.
However, if you want to do non-standard things, you have to roll your own.
